# 'package alread installed' in a newly created conda environment in wsl

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, conda

I created a new, empty conda environment:

```
$ conda create --name openai_test
```

I activate it:

```
(base) $ conda activate openai_test
```

Then try to install a package:

```
(openai_test) $ pip install openai
```

but I get:

```
(openai_test) $ pip install openai
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: openai in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (0.27.9)
Requirement already satisfied: requests>=2.20 in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from openai) (2.31.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tqdm in ./lib/python3.11/site-packages (from openai) (4.65.0)
...
```

Why? I just created a brand new environment so how come everything is 'already satisfied'?

Another thing I noticed is when I check for the pip location after activating the environment:

```
(openai_test) $ which pip
```

I get:

/

```
home/<user-name>/.local/bin/pip
```

Is this correct? Shouldn't pip be pointing to the conda installation directory?